# JOptionPane - input dialog box program

Tags: java, swing

Write a program that uses input dialog boxes to read three test marks, each out of 100. The program discards your lowest mark and shows the average of the two higher marks in a message dialog box.

This is how far i got and i dont know where to do from here, any help would be appreciated:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Average {

    public static void main (String [] args){

        String test1, test2, test3, avg;

        test1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input mark for test 1: ");

        test2= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input mark for test 2: ");

        test3= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input mark for test 3: ");

    }

}
```

Comment: See [these tips](http://home.earthlink.net/~patricia_shanahan/beginner.html) to get you started - if not to a solution, then at least for getting to the stage of asking a *specific* question.

Comment: 100,000 views for this question/answer. And I used it today. And yet it's closed for being too localized. Lol, ok.

Comment: FYI - This questions is #2 result when searching for combinations of 'java swing input alert'

Comment: In no way localized... This is a top result!

Answer (score 16):

```
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Average {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String test1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input mark for test 1: ");

        String test2= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input mark for test 2: ");

        String test3= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input mark for test 3: ");

        int int1 = Integer.parseInt(test1);
        int int2 = Integer.parseInt(test2);
        int int3 = Integer.parseInt(test3);

        SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
        set.add(int1);
        set.add(int2);
        set.add(int3);

        Integer [] intArray = set.toArray(new Integer[3]);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(frame.getContentPane(), String.format("Result %f", (intArray[1] + intArray[2]) / 2.0));

    }

}
```

Comment: I changed last line to the following to get it to work on Windows 10:



                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), String.format("Result %f", (intArray[1] + intArray[2]) / 2.0));

Answer (score 5):

Why to annoy the user with three different Dialog Boxes to enter things, why not do all this in one go in a single Dialog and save time, instead of testing the patience of the USER ?

You can add everything in a single Dialog, by putting all the fields on your `JPanel` and then adding this `JPanel` to your `JOptionPane`. Below code can clarify a bit more :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class AverageExample
{
    private double[] marks;
    private JTextField[] marksField;
    private JLabel resultLabel;

    public AverageExample()
    {
        marks = new double[3];
        marksField = new JTextField[3];
        marksField[0] = new JTextField(10);
        marksField[1] = new JTextField(10);
        marksField[2] = new JTextField(10);
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
                null, getPanel(), "Input Form : "
                                , JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION
                                , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        if (selection == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) 
        {
            for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                marks[i] = Double.valueOf(marksField[i].getText());             
            }
            Arrays.sort(marks);
            double average = (marks[1] + marks[2]) / 2.0;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null
                    , "Average is : " + Double.toString(average)
                    , "Average : "
                    , JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if (selection == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION)
        {
            // Do something here.
        }
    }

    private JPanel getPanel()
    {
        JPanel basePanel = new JPanel();
        //basePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        basePanel.setOpaque(true);
        basePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE.darker());

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2, 5, 5));
        centerPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel mLabel1 = new JLabel("Enter Marks 1 : ");
        JLabel mLabel2 = new JLabel("Enter Marks 2 : ");
        JLabel mLabel3 = new JLabel("Enter Marks 3 : ");

        centerPanel.add(mLabel1);
        centerPanel.add(marksField[0]);
        centerPanel.add(mLabel2);
        centerPanel.add(marksField[1]);
        centerPanel.add(mLabel3);
        centerPanel.add(marksField[2]);

        basePanel.add(centerPanel);

        return basePanel;
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new AverageExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to actually use an integer array instead of separate `test` strings:

You could loop  parse the response from `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` into the individual elements of the array.

`Arrays.sort` could be used to sort them to allow you to pick out the 2 highest values.

The average can be easily calculated then by adding these 2 values & dividing by 2.

```
int[] testScore = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < testScore.length; i++) {
   testScore[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input mark for test " + i + ": "));
}

Arrays.sort(testScore);
System.out.println("Average: " + (testScore[1] + testScore[2])/2.0);
```

Answer (score 2):

After that you have to parse the results.
Suppose results are in integers, then

```
int testint1 = Integer.parse(test1);
```

Similarly others should be parsed.
Now the results should be checked for two higher marks in them, by using if statement
After that take out the average.

Comment: how would i write the if statement when there are 3 numbers because you can't write if (test3<test2 and test3<test1) {

Comment: You can, if(test3<test2 && test3<test1) { if(test2<test1) { // means you got test3 and test2 greater here } else { // you got test 1 and test3 greater here } }

Comment: if i didnt want to use the && how else could i do this question?

Comment: Then move step by step. if(test3>test1) if(test3>test2) then it mean test3 is largest. now inside the same hierachy search the next maximum number. Or just simply use below example, sorting of array in descending order place the top most on the top of array.