# How to add a Java member button efficiently

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am pretty new to java and am creating a phone book application that allows users to either search by name or phone. You can search by name and get the user phone number or vice versa. I have hard coded the users in by using a 2D array, which I know is not very efficient. I would like to create a button that pops open a JDialog that lets the user type in a name and phone number and then that automatically puts the users name and number into the array. I know in order to do this I would probably need to use a Collection, like an arrayList or something but I wanted to see if somebody could guide me in the correct most efficient direction. Here is my code so far

```
public class PhoneBookGUI implements ActionListener{
JLabel name; 
JLabel number;
JLabel searchOptions;
JButton addButton; 
JTextField nameField;
JTextField numberField; 
JCheckBox ignoreCase; 
JRadioButton exactMatch; 
JRadioButton startsWithButton; 
JRadioButton endsWithButton;
String[][] phonelist = {
    {"Connor Littleton", "707-799-0194"},
    {"Justin Littleton", "707-799-0182"},
    {"Zia Thach", "707-123-4567"},
    {"Mike Hawk", "707-123-1234"},
    {"Sal Hal", "707-111-1111"}
};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new PhoneBookGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

PhoneBookGUI(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Phone-Book GUI"); 
    frame.setSize(300, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    name = new JLabel("Name:");
    number = new JLabel("Number:");
    searchOptions = new JLabel("Search Options:");
    nameField = new JTextField(10);
    numberField = new JTextField(10);
    ignoreCase = new JCheckBox("Ignore Case");
    exactMatch = new JRadioButton("Exact Match");
    startsWithButton = new JRadioButton("Starts With");
    endsWithButton = new JRadioButton("Ends With");
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(); 
    addButton = new JButton("Add Contact");
    buttonPane.add(addButton);
    ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup(); 

    nameField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
            numberField.setText(lookUpName(nameField.getText()));
        }
    });
    numberField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       @Override
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
           nameField.setText(lookUpNumber(numberField.getText()));
       } 
    });

    addButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            addButtonactionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    bg.add(exactMatch);
    bg.add(startsWithButton);
    bg.add(endsWithButton);

    frame.add(name);
    frame.add(nameField);
    frame.add(number);
    frame.add(numberField);
    frame.add(new JLabel());
    frame.add(buttonPane);
    frame.add(searchOptions);
    frame.add(ignoreCase);
    frame.add(new JLabel());
    frame.add(exactMatch);
    frame.add(startsWithButton);
    frame.add(endsWithButton);

}



public void addButtonactionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    addButtonMenu menu = new addButtonMenu(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true); 
    menu.setVisible(true);
}

public String lookUpNumber(String n){
    for (int i = 0; i < phonelist.length; i++) {
        if(phonelist[i][1].equals(n)){
            return phonelist[i][0];
        }
    }
    return "Not Found"; 
}

public String lookUpName(String n){
    for (int i = 0; i < phonelist.length; i++) {
        if(startsWithButton.isSelected()){
            if(ignoreCase.isSelected()){
                if(phonelist[i][0].toLowerCase().startsWith(n.toLowerCase()))
                    return phonelist [i][1]; 
                    }else{
                if(phonelist[i][0].startsWith(n))
                    return phonelist[i][1];
            }
        }
        else if(endsWithButton.isSelected()){
            if(ignoreCase.isSelected()){
                if(phonelist[i][0].toLowerCase().endsWith(n.toLowerCase()))
                    return phonelist[i][1]; 
            } else {
                if(phonelist[i][0].endsWith(n))
                    return phonelist[i][1]; 
            }
        }
        else {
            if(ignoreCase.isSelected()) {
                if(phonelist[i][0].toLowerCase().equals(n.toLowerCase()))
                    return phonelist[i][1]; 
                } else {
                    if(phonelist[i][0].equals(n))
                        return phonelist[i][1]; 
            }
        }
    }

    return "not found"; 
}

@Override 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

}
```

}

and here is my other page for the JDialog

```
public class addButtonMenu extends javax.swing.JDialog {

/**
 * Creates new form addButtonMenu
 */
public addButtonMenu(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    addFirstName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    firstNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    addLastName = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    lastNameField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    addMemberButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
    cancelMember = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Add Contact");
    setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 200));
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));

    addFirstName.setText("Full Name:");
    getContentPane().add(addFirstName);
    getContentPane().add(firstNameField);

    addLastName.setText("Phone Number:");
    getContentPane().add(addLastName);

    lastNameField.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            lastNameFieldActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(lastNameField);

    addMemberButton.setText("Submit");
    getContentPane().add(addMemberButton);

    cancelMember.setText("Cancel");
    cancelMember.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            cancelMemberActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(cancelMember);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void lastNameFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                             

private void cancelMemberActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    this.dispose();
}                                            

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(addButtonMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(addButtonMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(addButtonMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(addButtonMenu.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the dialog */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            addButtonMenu dialog = new addButtonMenu(new javax.swing.JFrame(), true);
            dialog.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent e) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel addFirstName;
private javax.swing.JLabel addLastName;
private javax.swing.JButton addMemberButton;
private javax.swing.JButton cancelMember;
private javax.swing.JTextField firstNameField;
private javax.swing.JTextField lastNameField;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use concept of **Hashtable** which stores key/value pairs in a hash table. When using a Hashtable, you specify an object that is used as a **key(Phone Number)**, and the **value (Name)** that you want linked to that key. The key is then hashed, and the resulting hash code is used as the **index** at which the value is stored within the table.
Use the idea of collections by using the following link, so it would be easy to sort and search the values for you,

[JOptionPane - input dialog box program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810460/joptionpane-input-dialog-box-program)

Or

You can use array but it would be a pain to handle it because 2D array store values in same data type while **Phone Number** should be parse as **int** **(Validate through regular expression)** while **name** use as **string**. Anyway use the given link to explore how 2D arrays works in JDialog.

http://forums.devshed.com/java-help/958183-form-data-2d-array-output-text-post2924712.html